# How to apply clustering on a cluster?

Tags: r, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, igraph

I used the R `library(igraph)` to make clusters on my dataset. I got several connected components but the first one is very huge, this is the giant component. I would like to reapply clustering on this giant component in order to rebuild clusters. Is it meaningful to do this?

Comment: I would treat those samples in the big cluster as a new dataset and reapply the clustering on them as a separate experiment.

Comment: I don't get it .. What do you mean by "treat those **samples** in the **big cluster**" ?

Comment: You could make a new graph of the data contained in the cluster you wish to re-cluster and perform your clustering on that graph.

Comment: That's what I tried actually. I extracted the data from the giant component and I consider it as a new dataset. I tried to apply clustering on this new dataset but that gave me back the same cluster.

Comment: Then maybe you should look into other clustering methods? But maybe that big component *is* a cluster?

Answer (score 0):

By its very nature, clustering has no meaning outside that which humans decide to give it. If you wish to split up your cluster into more clusters, then you need to tweak the hyper-parameters of the model you are using.

For example, K-means clustering allows you to select a priori the number of clusters you wish to have whilst density based clustering approaches typically allow you to define some density of significance. The library you're using doesn't look overly suited for clustering, but rather for graph calculations.

I'm not too familiar with R, but you may wish to try the [clusterR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ClusterR/ClusterR.pdf) package as this seems to have many common clustering algorithms. I myself tend to prefer Python for such things, in particular a package called [scikit-learn](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/scikit-learn).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What I mean in my comments is that I presume you have a dataset of samples (rows) and characteristics (columns).

If, for example, you do a K-means clustering on your whole dataset and get the results you say, I would create a new dataset where you only take the samples that belong to the big cluster. This way, you can apply whichever clustering technique on this new dataset by itself and it should split more.

This is because in your original dataset, as there are way bigger relative differences, the differences inside this big cluster are not considered important (they are way smaller). When you take the big differences out of the way, the small ones can be retrieved.